# Write a csv file to a kafka topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python, pykafka

I have a large csv and I want to write to a kafka topic.

```
def producer():
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='mykafka-broker')
    with open('/home/antonis/repos/testfile.csv') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            producer.send(topic='stable_topic', value=row)
            producer.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    producer()
```

This code produces an error:

```
AssertionError: value must be bytes
```

The file looks like:

```
"timestamp","name","age"
2020-03-01 00:00:01,John,36
2020-03-01 00:00:01,Peter,22
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly serialise your values.

---

The following should do the trick:

```
import json  

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers='mykafka-broker',
    value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than re-inventing the wheel, use the very good one that exists already :) It's [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html), which is part of Apache Kafka.

There are several connectors that can read from CSV including [Kafka Connect spooldir](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-spooldir/index.html) (see [example](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/)) and [Filepulse](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-filepulse-one-connector-to-ingest-them-all-faed018a725c).

Learn more about Kafka Connect in [this talk](https://talks.rmoff.net/DQkDj3/from-zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect).